# How to do a string compare between 2 arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to do a string compare between two arrays, the arrays are populated with text strings. When I get a match I want to count it and output the final amount at the end, e.g. if the two arrays have 100 elements each and the two arrays have 35 matches I want the output to state this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: paste the code, what you did for now.

Comment: Are the items in the arrays unique? Sorted? What have you tried?

Comment: if you are looking for a starting point then try http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php

Comment: Hey, look this useful sample: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php#95713

Comment: When you ask for code, providing a [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org) will increase your chances of help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`array_intersect($array1, $array2);`](https://www.php.net/array-intersect)

```
$returned = array_intersect($array1, $array2);
echo count($returned);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [array_intersect](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php) to find out the matched elements of two arrays.

```
 <?php
 $array1 = array("a" => "green", "red", "blue");
 $array2 = array("b" => "green", "yellow", "red");
 $result = array_intersect($array1, $array2);
 print_r($result);
 ?>
```

## Output

```
Array
(
[a] => green
[0] => red
)
```

Comment: Arghhhh just 11 seconds late... :p

Comment: Do note that `array_intersect` may produce unexpected results when there are duplicates in the arrays.

Comment: Add `echo count($result);` to print how many elements are returned.

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this

```
$data=array();
$count_matched=0;
$arr=array("abc","bcd","ghf","xxx","xcv","zsa");
$arr1=array("abc","bcd","ert","ccc","dfg","wer");
foreach($arr as $val)
{
    foreach($arr1 as $each)
    {
        if($val==$each)
        {
            $count_matched=$count_matched+1;
            break;
        }
    }
}
$data['match_count']=$count_matched;
echo "<pre>";print_r($data);die;
```